# Will amending a Git commit cause a issue for people who have already pulled?

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose you do a Git commit and then push to a remote repo. Then someone else pulls. Then you make a change and amend the commit.

When the amended commit is pushed and then pulled by someone else, will it cause a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; amending a commit creates an entirely new commit with a completely different SHA1 hash value (ID).  The rule of thumb is that you should never rebase or amend commits that have been pushed to a shared branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you amend the commit, then git refuses to push it, and you have to force push your branch (let's say it's master) with "+master". Whenever you need to force push a branch, then other people will have to manually resolve the conflict, when they pull it.